# Internet Explorer 11 crashes when Angulars $http.post is used with large/complex json datasets

Tags: json, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am consistently able to crash IE11 when I post large/complex json object using Angulars $http.post method.

I have setup an angular example which can be run in IE11 to see the behavior which I am experiencing: http://plnkr.co/edit/yYaDy8d00VGV6WcjaUu3?p=preview

This is the code which causes a crash:

```
$http.post($scope.saveDocumentUrl, { "document": doc, "submit": submit, "trash": trash }).success(function (data) {
            if (!data.Success) {
                bootbox.alert(data.Message);
            } else {
                if (trash) {
                    $scope.periodReviewDocuments.pop(doc);
                    hideModalWindow(); //we call this in the event that the method was called from the document and not from the list.
                }

                if(submit){
                    $scope.periodReviewDocuments.pop(doc);
                    resetForm();
                    bootbox.alert("Your document has been submitted");
                    hideModalWindow();                        
                }

            }
            $scope.isBusy = false;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.isBusy = false;
            bootbox.alert("The server encountered an error and could not save your document. If this problem persists please contact the administrators");
        });
```

This is the jquery working code:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: $scope.saveDocumentUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify({ "document": doc, "submit": submit, "trash": trash }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (!data.Success) {
                bootbox.alert(data.Message);
            } else {
                if (trash) {
                    $scope.periodReviewDocuments.pop(doc);
                    hideModalWindow(); //we call this in the event that the method was called from the document and not from the list.
                }

                if (submit) {
                    $scope.periodReviewDocuments.pop(doc);
                    resetForm();
                    bootbox.alert("Your document has been submitted");
                    hideModalWindow();
                }

            }
            $scope.isBusy = false;
        }).fail(function (data, status) {
                $scope.isBusy = false;
                bootbox.alert("The server encountered an error and could not save your document. If this problem persists please contact the administrators");
        })
```

This is what I know so far:

1. This issue only happens in IE11 - Windows 8.1 / IE 11 (11.0.9600.17498). Update versions 11.0.15 (KB3008923).
2. The browser crashes after the request is sent.
3. I have inspected the server side incoming request and the payload has been serialised/deserialised perfectly.
4. I have replaced the $http.post function with jquery $.ajax and it resolved the issue, but this is not a solution as I am using angular.
5. I have lost 3 days on this issue

Comment: I work on the IE team and am able to repro the issue with your demo. I'll get this to the rest of the team for review immediately and relay any necessary feedback. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: how many items does your response have? can you get away with paging and lazy loading the records?

Comment: @JonathanSampson thanks very much - let me know if you need any further detail.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon - I know the request is super huge - i will work on optimising it. I do not think that size is the issue here, as other requests of similar size (and larger) are successfully posting on the same method.

Comment: @user3301508 If you are able to recreate the issue with a smaller payload, that would be very helpful. The smaller, the better. I'm working on getting a crash dump from my end.

Comment: I've collected a crash dump analysis, and have opened up an issue on this for our team to investigate further. Thank you again for reporting the matter.

Comment: any news on this? I believe I am seeing the same issue.

Comment: @TrentVB There is an issue with posting large json objects. I found that I could post the stringified object, but not a complex/large JSON object. perhaps try null the properties of your object which you don't need to post?

Comment: I figured out my issue which turned out to be unrelated. The code was flagging the form element with ng-disabled right before it kicked off the POST.......apparently IE really really really doesn't like <form disabled>.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Hmm, I think I could isolate the issue a little more by digging through [angular source code](http://goo.gl/hmK7gq) and making a few assumptions until reproduce the [same problem but now with a reduced the code: `JSON.stringify(obj, fn, indent)`](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7AiamvZYeb7b0Smf98j?p=preview). Note that I could also reproduce it with `angular.toJson(data)` (called on `$http.post`). I'd recommend to take a look at [this open source JSON implementation](http://goo.gl/ulfnxU), recommended by [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Comment: @user3301508 I'm not sure what would be an *answer* to your *question*...

Comment: I was looking for a definitive reason as to why a script is crashing the browser. 

I eventually just settled with a workaround: split up the request into smaller objects.

Comment: As a side note, I debugged the crash in WinDbg and it looks exploitable.

Comment: It might take a few tries to repro a non null pointer crash however.

Comment: @Sampson hey any news on this issue?

Comment: It was long fixed by a security update, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your version of Internet Explorer calling JSON.stringify with a translation filter crashes IE for large data sets.

The trick here is to stringify the object yourself before passing to $http.post

http://plnkr.co/edit/PbMxMY?p=preview

```
  var body = {"document" .....

  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(body);

  $http.post("/test", jsonData).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });

  $interval(function() {
    $rootScope.tick = Date.now();
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Agree - this is a way to avoid the issue, but I had already written hundereds of endpoints by the time this IE bug came to existance... it was not an option for me to go and change every endpoint to accept a serialised string :(

Comment: We use a common service wrapper around post calls so it was easy for us to implement this fix.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in this month's IE updates, probably by https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3075516

As a side note, you can detect this by using ScriptEngineBuildVersion in JavaScript. Make sure you also use ScriptEngineMajorVersion and ScriptEngineMinorVersion and refer to the file information in the KB article.